# Segment fault occurs depend on cpp sequence in gcc compile command?

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault

I write a simple program that adds a value into a global set container when a new class (eg: One,Two) is defined:

GlobalSet.h

```
#include <set>
struct GlobalSet{
public:
    static void* addValue(int val);
private:
    static std::set<int> s;
};
```

GlobalSet.cpp

```
#include "GlobalSet.cpp"
std::set<int> GlobalSet::s;
void* GlobalSet::addValue(int val){
    s.insert(val);
    return NULL;
}
```

One.h

```
struct One{};
```

One.cpp

```
#include "One.h"
#include "GlobalSet.h"
void* globalset =GlobalSet::addValue(1);
```

Two.h

```
struct Two{};
```

Two.cpp

```
#include "Two.h"
#include "GlobalSet.h"
void* globalset2 =GlobalSet::addValue(2);
```

test.cpp

```
int main(){
return 0;
}
```

But this program will cause segment fault depend on cpp sequence in gcc compile command:

```
g++ GlobalSet.cpp One.cpp Two.cpp test.cpp -o test.exe //normal
g++ One.cpp Two.cpp GlobalSet.cpp test.cpp -o test.exe //segment fault!!
```

Why would it happen? How to fix the problem so that it works without care the sequence of cpp in gcc compilation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

The C++ standard does not guarantee the initialization order of global objects in multiple translation units.

Depending on your link order, your code will attempt to construct `globalset2` first. However, this calls a static class method `addValue()`, which attempts to access a `std::set` that has not been constructed, yet.

Undefined behavior, and a crash.

To fix this, go to www.google.com, search for "static initialization order fiasco", and keep reading, until you understand the issue. Once you do, you will know what to do to fix it, in your code.